# SSRS join(Parameters!ACCNUMBER.Value, ",") generate rendering error

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2012

i am building a SSRS report using report builder 3.0.
i have parameter ACCNUMBER which contain a large number or records, and i am using inside my report the below function :

```
join(Parameters!ACCNUMBER.Value, ",")
```

when i generate the report for and i selected few values from ACCNUMBER parameter the report is generated normally; however if i generate the report while Select All values in ACCNUMBER parameter, i receive the below error:

[image]

appreciate your assistance.

Comment: the report is properly generated up to 1000 record in parameter.
if the parameter contain 1001 and above it will generate an error.

i tried to add the below code in web.config file under Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager)
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="20000" />
but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are on the right track but just need to also update the value for `MaxJsonDeserializerMembers`.

> There is a (c)onstraint (on .NET framework or Web server I think) that allows only 1,000 values to be loaded under parameter drop down boxes

---

> Add the following tags under  section. Note: If
>     doesn't exists in config files add the whole tag from
>   below just after <\system.web> section. If "appSettings" is already
>   there just add 2 keys from below. I put 30000 as maximum number of
>   items, but you can use any number of values.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="30000" />
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="30000" />
</appSettings>
```

[From Mladen's MS BI Blog](https://sqlsrv4living.blogspot.com/2012/10/sql-reporting-services-maximum-number.html)